# Froala Editor doesn't work after append dinamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I have a problem with dinamically content.

I have a variable:

```
var editorInlineHorari = new FroalaEditor('#froala-editor-inline-horari', {
toolbarInline: true,
toolbarButtons: [
    ['bold', 'italic'],
    ['textColor', 'backgroundColor']
],
events: {
    contentChanged: function () {
        console.log(this.html.get());
    }
},
spellcheck: false
});
```

That it's called by default but when I insert new element into my table by the code:

```
$('#tbody_horari').append(FILA_HORARI);
```

where FILA_HORARI it's a new TR table, the new handler doesn't work and I cant edit my text inside.

```
const FILA_HORARI = `<tr>
    <td id="froala-editor-inline-horari" class="text-center h6 font-weight-light align-middle">Editar Hora</td>
    <td id="froala-editor-inline-horari" class="text-center align-middle bg-white">Editar</td>
    <td id="froala-editor-inline-horari" class="text-center align-middle bg-white">Editar</td>
    <td id="froala-editor-inline-horari" class="text-center align-middle bg-white">Editar</td>
    <td id="froala-editor-inline-horari" class="text-center align-middle bg-white">Editar</td>
    <td id="froala-editor-inline-horari" class="text-center align-middle bg-white">Editar</td>
</tr>`;
```

How can I handle again this texts?

Comment: actually what you are trying to achieve here? PS: setting same ID for several elements in not a right thing.

Comment: Oh I believe this post.. jeje It just work if I change id attribute to class attribute. Thanks. I just append dynamiclly and then call froala again.